# Archived Server for Reference - Unable to Navigate Passed Homepage

Tags: server, cloud

I recently moved to a cloud-hosted WordPress instance from an outdated on-prem server. As reference, the on-prem server is still available locally. However, I am unable to navigate to any of the individual blogs hosted on the server. I can make it to the homepage, but after that all other pages result in 404 pages when requested.

This issue is occurring on a Windows workstation with a manually set hosts file which points the website/domain name to the on-prem server. I have also verified that I can pull up individual media files through the site (i.e. `https://sitename.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/101/...`) without issue when requesting manually.

The server is running CentOS with Apache/2.2.15 and worked perfectly fine prior to the DNS cut-over.

Thoughts on how I can go back and view the content on the old server for reference?

Comment: sounds like a rewrite issue, as physical files load fine. did you flush permalinks or try with standard - non-pretty - structure?

Comment: @QStudio I have not. Honestly, I’m a bit new to WP. Do you know of any good resources on those two items?

Comment: Can you login to the wp-admin? if so, you can just visit Settings > Permalinks